# Azure Cloud Service - Auto Scale by queue counts Invisible messages (not ready for processing)

Tags: azure-cloud-services, autoscaling, azure-queues

We just developed a system that integrates azure queue with an azure cloud service to process batch items.  One requirement we had was to have items be set in the future to process. So for example, we batch it now, but tell it not to start for 5 hours.

This is built right into azure queues AddMessage using initialVisibilityDelay, so we did not see this as being an issue.  However, we just noticed when we add auto scale on our Cloud Service, it is going off the total items in queue.  In our situation we added 100,000 queue items to be sent 5 days from now, however it is scaling assuming these 100,000 are ready to go right now.

So in our situation, we would basically have dozens of instances of our app running until these messages can even send, 5 days from now.

I feel like there is something simple we are missing here.

Any feedback would be very helpful.

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using one queue for the waiting messages and another queue for the actual messages to be processed and scaling on that latter queue?

Comment: We already do this to handle messages over 7 days in queue.  We have a "long queue" queue that reschedules the queue till its under 7 days. That is our next option but we have dozens of queues and this is adding just more overhead and more points of failure.

I think our better option is to scale our-self via the API, however again that goes to another point where things can just fail when our assumption is this was a basic feature built in.

Why azure would scale based on size, yet count items that are not ready to run, makes no sense to us.

Comment: *"Why azure would scale based on size, yet count items that are not ready to run, makes no sense to us"* - I agree, the functionality does seem basic (e.g. I would like the scale on SB Queues / Topics, not just Storage Queues).

Comment: It just seems like there has to be a better / build in way. For now I am going to leave this open, to see if anyone else can answer it, but if after a few days no one has I will mark this as the answer.  We are actually going to do it this way for right now, since we already had it built for "Over 7 day delayed" and literally just got to change an int for this to work.  However long term, that doesn't seem like a good solution, and will likely handle the scale our self in coding.

Comment: Azure support responded with the same answer, use a 2nd queue (which more the question is how do i scale that 2nd queue correctly) so in the end looks like I need to figure the scale out myself.   Thanks for the advice!